# Can I use a single stator coil to actuate/rotate two rotors inside and outside of the stator

Tags: electrical-engineering, stepper-motor

I want to design a motor system where a single stator coil is responsible for two rotors of neodymium magnets on its outside and inside, will this work, and what are the downsides I should be expecting? Any advice on perfecting the design will be very helpful.

Comment: I highly doubt it works properly, the outside rotor experience a huge mmf fall duo to the large air gap, and if you mange somehow to keep the field confined by reduction of the air gap, the outsider generates a rotating field which in turn affects the working of stator/rotor(inside). I guess, it first start rotating, but then Lenz's law implies that the two rotors try to cancel each other out.

Comment: Just so you know the rotors are moving in opposite direction relative to each other. And the air gap won't be a problem.

Comment: Then what are you waiting for go and build your spaceship before the man in black come and get you.

Comment: Funny! Really Funny!

Comment: Yes, I can give design advise, but I'd need the more detail specs. I work on projects like this often. - Dennis #NeoMagMan